# Nativescript webpack 2.2.0 android release apk is crashing after splash screen in device

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Hi I am using Nativescript 2.5.2 & Angular 2 and webpack 2.2.0 to bundle the app.
I followed all the instructions for 'webpack' and successfully build ios release for device and its working fine

```
npm run build-ios-bundle -- --release --for-device
```

And in android below is working and app running fine in device/genymotion

```
npm run start-android-bundle
```

**But when I build the app with release key store build was successfull but app is crashing in device after splashscreen.**

```
npm run build-android-bundle -- --release --key-store-path /Users/maisapride7/workspace/KIDSAPP/tingr-teacher-key.jks --key-store-password tingr786 --key-store-alias my-alias --key-store-alias-password tingr786
```

and without webpack the release apk working fine in device without any crash

```
tns build android --release --key-store-path /Users/maisapride7/workspace/KIDSAPP/tingr-teacher-key.jks --key-store-password tingr786 --key-store-alias my-alias --key-store-alias-password tingr786
```

***Can any one please help me why its not working for webpack build for release with keystore?***

below is my package.json file

```
{
  "description": "app description..",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "...",
  "repository": "....",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.tingr.teacher",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.5.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.5",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "1.4.1",
    "nativescript-cardview": "^1.2.1",
    "nativescript-carousel": "^2.2.0",
    "nativescript-dom": "^1.0.8",
    "nativescript-fresco": "^1.0.16",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^2.4.1",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.2.2",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^3.10.2",
    "nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^1.1.10",
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^0.2.1",
    "nativescript-toasts": "^1.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.2.10",
    "babel-traverse": "6.8.0",
    "babel-types": "6.8.1",
    "babylon": "6.8.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-css-loader": "~0.26.0",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "0.0.7",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.3.6",
    "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "~1.6.0",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.0",
    "webpack-sources": "~0.1.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ns-bundle": "ns-bundle",
    "start-android-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --android --start-app",
    "start-ios-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --ios --start-app",
    "build-android-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --android --build-app",
    "build-ios-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app"
  }
}
```

Comment: show the error to facilitate identification of the bug

Comment: @DouglasFranco , I was enabled crash reporting in firebase but no logs are saving.I am new to android and can you please help me how to check logs for release apk in genymotion or my mobile device..

Comment: genymotion by default show a log trace at the display of emulator when app crashes, then you could copy and paste here.

Comment: post some logs so that i can help you?

Comment: the dialog shown  unfortunately 'appname' closed try to to resolve or ok buttons are showing its release apk and that the problem.

Comment: can you please help here how to know the log for release versioned of apk

Comment: Is your build is working fine without bundling it?

Comment: yes its working fine with ..
tns build android --release --key-store-path ......
But now working with 
pm run build-android-bundle -- --release --key-store-path

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after running 'tns platform remove android && tns platform add android'

```
npm run build-android-bundle -- --key-store-path my-key-store-path/my-key-store-filename[.jks | .keystore] --key-store-password my-key-store-password --key-store-alias my-alias --key-store-alias-password my-alias-password --release --for-device
```